# How to embed an one index file to another index file?

Tags: php, server-side-includes

**The page I'm working on(php project) has a classical left-sidebar menu**.

- Under one of menu-elements I want to show the user "Phpsysinfo"(embed the index.php file of phpsysinfo extension folder into my page).
- I'm avoiding iframe, so is there any other way to do this? Should i use server side include for this, if yes how?

**code:**

```
 <div id="php_sys_info">
    <?php <!--#include file="../../extension/phpsysinfo-3.1.11/index.php" --> ?>
</div>
```

**please resolve my problem.**

Comment: `<?php include "../../extension/phpsysinfo-3.1.11/index.php"; ?>`?

Comment: Actually tried it before but it failed!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you can directly load that page using load method my way is like this.For this you require jquery.

```
 <script>
  $('#php_sys_info').load('../../extension/phpsysinfo-3.1.11/index.php');    
</script>
<div id="php_sys_info">

</div>
```

Comment: It's not still working but I'm going to work on doing this with jquery. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: call load function on any event like click or directly call it in event $(document).ready(function(){$('#php_sys_info').load('../../extension/phpsysinfo-3.1.11/index.php'); }); like this it will surely work

Comment: load() helped anyway. Phpsysinfo page causes the main problem. Since it redirects to some target page and fails loading. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this:

[include()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)